# Fetched data with key of type objects are undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

I try to learn a bit about fetching from APIs but have a hard time.
Can someone explain me, why the `pokemon['sprites']['back_default']` is undefined,
but `pokemon['name']` works just fine?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Mybutton() {
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState("");

    const getPokemon = () => {
      fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/").then(
        (response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPokemon(data);
        });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={getPokemon}>Get pOKIMON</button>
        {pokemon['name']}
        {pokemon.sprites[0].back_default}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I tried to Google the problem, but I don't know, what exactly I am looking for!

Comment: The obvious answers are (a) the pokemon object does not contains a "sprites" key, (b)  pokemon.sprites exists but it is not a list, or (c) pokemon.sprites[0] does not contain a key called "back_default".  You need to do some debugging here to print the intermediate steps.

Comment: When I fetch that page (Charmander), "sprites" is not an array.  Get rid of the `[0]`.  You know that "pOKIMON" is misspelled, right?

Comment: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4 shows that `.sprites` is an object.

Comment: Sorry i pasted a wrong version! But even when i type pokemon["sprites"]["back_default"] i get undefined?

Comment: When the component is first rendered `pokemon` will be an empty string. So `prokemon.sprites.back_default` will be undefined

Comment: So how do i solve this? I thought i just safe the entire JSON of the API in the pokemon variable. Then i could just normally access its keys? pokemon["name"] just works fine, but pokemon["sprites"]["back_default"] doesnt? Every key which is not an object just works fine, but the key which contain object doesnt work!

Comment: i suggest you to post us the JSON, is much easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

When react tries to render the component initially pokemon variable holds nothing. hence it throws an error. So you have to check if the variable is empty or not.

```
{pokemon && pokemon['name']} //check if pokemon is empty
{pokemon && pokemon.sprites[0]?.back_default} // check if pokemon and sprites[0] exists
```

also, you can define the state variable as empty since you dont intend to store a string in it.

```
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState();
```

Comment: Can't i do something like saying in the getPokemon function to wait until everything is fetched? Because pokemon["name"] just works fine, but when i access the objects its undefined?